# TextView from Map

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, javafx

I Have a `Map<String, Integer>`
I need to print all values into textView.
I used this code, but it prints only last value, not all

```
int count = 0;
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list){
    count++;
    textView.setText(count + "   " + entry.getKey()+"    "+entry.getValue());
}
```

what do i do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep overwriting the text each iteration.

You would need to append each value to a string.

Eg.

```
int count = 0;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:list) {
    count++;
    builder.append(count + "   " + entry.getKey()+"    "+entry.getValue());
} 

textView.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: Tnx, but it write all text in 1 line.
How should it may write each key+value in new line?

Comment: I've lead you far enough with this answer. You need to do a bit of research on your own to figure out the rest.

Comment: Hint: Its just placed just after `entry.getValue()`